# Primefaces - selectOneListbox - nothing happens

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My Primefaces 8.0 application needs to show a Candidate list. When I do not select any candidate, the command button invokes the save() method. But, when I choose some candidate, nothing happens. No errors, no exception. The method save() is not invoked.

The xhtml

```
<p:selectOneListbox value="#{myBean.candidateSelected}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.candidateList}"
      var="optCandidate"
      itemLabel="#{optCandidate.name}"
      itemValue="#{optCandidate}"
   />
</p:selectOneListbox>

<p:commandButton value="save" 
   actionListener="#{myBean.save}"
/>
```

The class

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {

    private SelectItem candidateSelected; 
    private List<SelectItem> candidateList;
    
    public void save(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Saving...");
    }
//getters,setters and populating candidateList
}
```

any clue?

Thank you!

Comment: See abovelinked duplicates. The first duplicate describes at #3 how to get validation/conversion error message to display. The second duplicate describes how to properly populate and declare select items.

Comment: look if you don't have form